# Can't access $_POST variables when using multipart/form-data

Tags: php

**What is the problem?**

When I add a file using my form the $_POST variables are undefined. When I don't add a file the $_POST variables are defined.

**What errors do you receive?**

```
Notice: Undefined index: bbmpin in C:\...\addpin.php on line 6
Notice: Undefined index: usermsg in C:\...\addpin.php on line 7
```

**Source Code**

index.html

```
<form method="POST" action="addpin.php"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div>
            <label for="bbmpin">Your BBM Pin</label>
            <input type="text" name="bbmpin" placeholder="Enter Your BBM Pin">
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="usermsg">Message</label>
            <input type="text" name="usermsg" placeholder="(optional) Add a short message" maxlength="255">
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="image">Upload Image <small>(optional)</small></label>
            <input type="file" name="image"> 
        </div>

        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

addpin.php

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once('config/config.php');

$pin = $_POST['bbmpin'];
$msg = $_POST['usermsg'];
$ip  = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

print_r($_POST);
print_r($_FILES);
    exit;

    ...
?>
```

Comment: what is the size of the uploaded item? probably your server has a limit for posted data size.

Comment: I believe the issue may be something to do with uploading a file larger than the max file size in the ini.php. If I upload a small image it works fine.

Comment: @pinusnegra yeah I think it is that. I just posted the same thing as you did. What's the best way to ensure the user does not see that error? So I can redirect them to an error page?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the post size exceeds the allowed maximum, the $_POST superglobal array will be empty.

So you have to check if file upload suceeds be checking the $_FILES array or checking the $_POST array.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

If you need to increase the post size limit, you should check this php.ini directive

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size

And maybe you will need to change it in your web server configuration (I don't know which one do you use)